# django-pyodbc vs django-mssql

Tags: sql-server, django, database-connection, django-pyodbc, django-mssql

It's in the title really. I want to run Django against MSSQL 2005. Both look reasonably active and up to date. I can't seem to see any unique points for either.

- Can anyone recommend one over the other?
- Would it be trivial to swap between the two at a later date?
- Are they production-ready?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My choose is django-pyodbc because of cross-platform requirements.
django-mssql runs only on Windows.

Django-pyodbc works with South.

Django-pyodbc has some bugs and pyodbc itself too. I've patched both (I found code somewhere).
First problem was inserting keys which are identity (i.e. autoincremented) in DB when running 'manage.py ss_loaddata' command. ss_loaddata is a special command for this backend instead of 'loaddata'. Second problem... I don't remember this.

As I see, django-mssql have bugs too, but, I hope, less than pyodbc. I haven't try it yet.

May be, both are stable now :)

Comment: django-mssql is designed to only interface with SQL server and makes certain optimizations and assumptions based upon that fact, where as django-pyodbc is a generic ODBC backend.

Comment: Also, at the moment, django-pyodbc does not support REGEX queries, whereas django-mssql does. I think that might be important for some decisions.